# Get variables from .xlam to a .xlsb

Tags: excel, vba, variables, global-variables

Recently I discovered about .xlam files to reuse functions that I use in several files. I'm not a programmer so this is maybe something easy but I've been hours into this and I can't find the way to solve it.

I've just created a project with some of the functions that I used most and I saved the file in a Sharepoint site. After that I created a Reference and everything seems to be working well. I can Call functions just with a

```
 call FunctionName()
```

And the functions are running well. But I haven't found the way to return global variables from the .xlam file to my .xlsb file
I'm defining a Global variable just like this in a Module in the .xlam

```
Global CRegion As String
```

In the same module I have this easy macro:

```
Function GetRegion()
CRegion = Range("B2").Value
End Function
```

And then in my .xlsb file Im testing something like this after calling the GetRegion Function.

```
Msgbox CRegion
```

The result is an empty Message Box. I've tried to define a global variable with the same name in my .xlsb file and it still does not work.

¿Any clue to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have not tested it, but try:

> To make a public variable available to other workbooks, from a new workbook select the workbook containing the public variable in the Available References box of the References dialog box (from a module sheet, click References on the Tools menu).

Source: MSDN

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141693

Comment: This worked as an example to get what I needed!. I had already made the Reference, but i found that I only had to get the variable with the ModuleName.GlobalVariableName  Thank you very much! It was useful!